# Using Terraform to setup multiple Tags for AWS Config using approved-amis-by-tag

Tags: terraform, tags, aws-config

I have a problem understanding how to add multiple tags into AWS Config for the config rule approved-amis-by-tag using Terraform.

This is my setup:

```
# AWS Config Rule that checks if the AMIs used are in the list of compliant AMIs
resource "aws_config_organization_managed_rule" "approved-amis-by-tag" {

depends_on = [
  aws_config_configuration_recorder.config_recorder
]

name            = "approved-amis-by-tag"
rule_identifier = "APPROVED_AMIS_BY_TAG"

input_parameters = <<EOF
{
  "amisByTagKeyAndValue": {
    "approvedAmiLinux": "amazonLinux",
    "approvedAmiLinux2": "amazonLinux2",
    "approvedAmiUbuntu20.04": "Ubuntu20.04",
    "approvedAmiUbuntu22.04": "Ubuntu22.04"
  }
}
EOF

timeouts {
  create = "10m"
  delete = "10m"
  update = "10m"
  }
}
```

When I run this using terraform -plan it works as expected. As soon as I try to deploy it to AWS using terraform apply, I get the following error message:

> Error: error creating Config Organization Managed Rule (approved-amis-by-tag): InvalidParameterValueException: Blank spaces are not acceptable for input parameter: amisByTagKeyAndValue.
> │
> │   with aws_config_organization_managed_rule.approved-amis-by-tag,
> │   on 07_config.tf line 102, in resource "aws_config_organization_managed_rule" "approved-amis-by-tag":
> │  102: resource "aws_config_organization_managed_rule" "approved-amis-by-tag" {

How do I need to formulate "amisByTagKeyAndValue" so that this works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely due to an issue with the JSON formatting in your string. This would be more easily and confidently accomplished with `jsonencode`:

```
input_parameters = jsonencode({
  "amisByTagKeyAndValue" = {
    "approvedAmiLinux"       = "amazonLinux",
    "approvedAmiLinux2"      = "amazonLinux2",
    "approvedAmiUbuntu20.04" = "Ubuntu20.04",
    "approvedAmiUbuntu22.04" = "Ubuntu22.04"
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives me the same error unfortunately :/

Comment: @Benny A different error would certainly be possible, but the same error is suspicious when using this answer. Are you certain you used this answer in your config and that nothing else is causing an error?

Comment: I have now tried to use jsonencode twice at input_parameters and at amisByTagKeyAndValue and that works, so yes it was indeed still the issue at this point, but your solution helped me so thanks a lot!